# Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root. while creating docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, next.js, docker-image, docker-build

I am trying to create a docker image but I am getting this error(Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root) in the "npm run build" step. But I have that directory in my application root folder. In my local server it is running fine and creating .next folder. My folder structure is ex: app/pages/index.js
I don't know why it is failing in the docker build. Can you guys help me with this?

Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/next-website
WORKDIR /usr/src/next-website
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i
RUN npm run build
COPY . .
EXPOSE 94
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At the point where you `RUN npm run build`, you have only `COPY` the `package.json` file in, but not the rest of the application.  Move this line after the following `COPY . .` line.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it is working fine.
Cheers!!

Comment: @DavidMaze I think you should add your comment as the answer.