# Error: > Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root

Tags: docker, next.js, cloud

```
~/beb-03-ball93# docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 forblocksungjin/front

>next-cosmwasm-keplr-starter@0.1.0 dev
>next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000

Error: > Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root

    at Object.findPagesDir (/front-end/node_modules/next/dist/lib/find-pages-dir.js:39:15)
    at new DevServer (/front-end/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:137:73)
    at NextServer.createServer (/front-end/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:106:20)
    at /front-end/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:121:42
    at async NextServer.prepare (/front-end/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:96:24)
    at async /front-end/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js:127:9
:~/beb-03-ball93# client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

this is problem with docker and Digitalocean droplets

i'll keep updated

what's the problem?

Comment: Could you please show us your Dockerfile?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67302109/couldnt-find-a-pages-directory-please-create-one-under-the-project-root-whi